# How to expose a Rust `Vec<T>` to FFI?

Tags: rust, ffi

I'm trying to construct a pair of elements:

- `array: *mut T`
- `array_len: usize`

`array` is intended to own the data

However, [`Box::into_raw`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.into_raw) will return `*mut [T]`. I cannot find any info on converting raw pointers to slices. What is its layout in memory? How do I use it from C? Should I convert to `*mut T`? If so, how?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you just want some C function to mutably borrow the `Vec`, you can do it like this:

```
extern "C" {
    fn some_c_function(ptr: *mut i32, len: ffi::size_t);
}

fn safe_wrapper(a: &mut [i32]) {
    unsafe {
        some_c_function(a.as_mut_ptr(), a.len() as ffi::size_t);
    }
}
```

Of course, the C function shouldn't store this pointer somewhere else because that would break aliasing assumptions.

If you want to "pass ownership" of the data to C code, you'd do something like this:

```
use std::mem;

extern "C" {
    fn c_sink(ptr: *mut i32, len: ffi::size_t);
}

fn sink_wrapper(mut vec: Vec<i32>) {
    vec.shrink_to_fit();
    assert!(vec.len() == vec.capacity());
    let ptr = vec.as_mut_ptr();
    let len = vec.len();
    mem::forget(vec); // prevent deallocation in Rust
                      // The array is still there but no Rust object
                      // feels responsible. We only have ptr/len now
                      // to reach it.
    unsafe {
        c_sink(ptr, len as ffi::size_t);
    }
}
```

Here, the C function "takes ownership" in the sense that we expect it to eventually return the pointer and length to Rust, for example, by calling a Rust function to deallocate it:

```
#[no_mangle]
/// This is intended for the C code to call for deallocating the
/// Rust-allocated i32 array.
unsafe extern "C" fn deallocate_rust_buffer(ptr: *mut i32, len: ffi::size_t) {
    let len = len as usize;
    drop(Vec::from_raw_parts(ptr, len, len));
}
```

Because `Vec::from_raw_parts` expects three parameters, a pointer, a size and a capacity, we either have to keep track of the capacity as well somehow, or we use Vec's `shrink_to_fit` before passing the pointer and length to the C function. This might involve a reallocation, though.

Comment: That's what I end up using: <https://github.com/maidsafe/safe_core/pull/321/files#diff-6c72b345033f35005d017f9f5a1e1c9eR60>. Except for the `assert!`, which I was thinking about using, but I wasn't confident/convinced enough.

Comment: I have no clue why but if you have a Vec with 0 length/capacity/size, and you do `.as_mut_ptr()`, it returns `0x1` (aka an invalid pointer).

Comment: The docs for [`Vec::shrink_to_fit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.shrink_to_fit) suggest that your assertion `assert!(vec.len() == vec.capacity());` is not always correct (the docs only assert `capacity() >= len()`). [This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74555791/12299000) concerns essentially the same problem, so I mentioned this answer there, but that question is specifically about the possibility that `shrink_to_fit` isn't exact, which doesn't seem to be addressed here but does seem to be relevant.

Answer (score 10):

You could [use `[T]::as_mut_ptr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.as_mut_ptr) to obtain the `*mut T` pointer directly from `Vec<T>`, `Box<[T]>` or any other DerefMut-to-slice types.

```
use std::mem;

let mut boxed_slice: Box<[T]> = vector.into_boxed_slice();

let array: *mut T = boxed_slice.as_mut_ptr();
let array_len: usize = boxed_slice.len();

// Prevent the slice from being destroyed (Leak the memory).
mem::forget(boxed_slice);
```

Comment: will `array` be valid once the `vector` is destroyed? The idea is that `array` will own the data (I'll update the question).

Comment: @vinipsmaker: No. Therefore, keep the vector from being destroyed by `forget`ting it. See update.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused how the deallocation code would work within this approach. `into_boxed_slice` will return... what's the layout of that in memory? `boxed_slice.as_mut_ptr()` is guaranteed to return a pointer to the first char? How do I convert back to `Box<[T]>` so I can deallocate?

Comment: @vinipsmaker: (1) the layout is not specified. the current implementation uses `(ptr, len)`. (2) perhaps you should ask a new question. but you could try `slice::from_raw_parts_mut` and `Box::from_raw`, or use `Vec::from_raw_parts` but you need to pass the capacity as well.

Comment: How `slice::from_raw_parts` + `Box::from_raw` would be okay here? Isn't `Box::from_raw` getting a pointer to the stack-allocated slice and not the original slice? Or `Box<[T]>` is a special case?

Comment: @vinipsmaker: The result of `slice::from_raw_parts_mut(array, array_len)` will refer to your heap-allocated memory. There is no stack allocation for any array involved here. And `Box::from_raw` will take ownership of it again so it'll be properly deallocated when it's dropped. But all this basically boils down to `Vec::from_raw_parts(array, array_len, array_len)` with the vec taking ownership of it again. BTW: `into_boxed_slice` is important here as it reduces the capacity to match the size. Otherwise you'd need to remember the original capacity as well.

Comment: @sellibitze: can you link me to a reference? `Box::drop` is different than `slice::Drop` (I know `slice` is just a view and have no need to `drop`...).  As far as I see, unless `Box` gives special treatment to `slice`, it cannot know the `slice` heap-allocated content (pointers stored internally by `slice`). All `Box` should see is `slice` as an opaque box.

Comment: @vinipsmaker: To be honest, I have trouble understanding where you think a problem is. `Box::from_raw` cannot know what the given pointer refers to. It just expects the pointer to come from some other `Box` that is now gone without having deallocated the pointee. So, you could feed it with some other pointer and violate this assumption. That's why this function is marked `unsafe`.

Comment: If I understood correctly, `Box` is a smart pointer and it'll manage the heap-allocated memory. It'll use Rust's move semantics to move data from stack to heap without problems (there are no shared mutable state), but it's `Box` who will call deallocate. `Box<T>::into_raw` returns a pointer to `T` and it doesn't care about T's internal structure. `T`, in my case, is `slice` and AFAIK `Box` won't deallocate the region pointed by the `slice`. `slice` doesn't have `drop`. Only if `Box` gives special treatment to `slice` I can see how this work.

Comment: I just can't see a guarantee I want on Rust for `Box<T>`: <https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html>. C++ smart pointers are better documented. I can know exactly who is responsible to deallocate memory: <http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr>. I'm using an unsafe API, there is a reason why I'm worried. And Rust see memory leaks as safe (but realistically you'd only need to worry if you need an unsafe API as well).

Comment: @vinipsmaker: `Box::from_raw` is like `unique_ptr`'s constructor taking a raw pointer. `Box::into_raw` is like `unique_ptr::release`. So, given one box `b` you can do `Box::from_raw(b.into_raw())` which is similar to C++'s `unique_ptr<int>(otherptr.release())` if `otherptr` is also a `unique_ptr<int>`. What your `T` is doesn't really matter. Both `unique_ptr` and `Box` support arrays as well: `unique_ptr<int[]>` or `Box<[i32]>`. This is properly deallocated/destroyed, too. You may be confusing this with a *borrowed* slice `&[i32]` which is just a reference and dropping it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @vinipsmaker: Also, a borrowed reference/slice coerces to a raw pointer. So, given a "borrowed slice" of type `&mut [i32]` that's not really borrowed but the result of `slice::from_raw_parts_mut` you can stick it into `Box::from_raw` since it automatically turns into a `*mut [i32]`. The functions involved are all unsafe, of course, because it's easy to misuse. You must not use `Box::from_raw` with something that's already owned by something else or with something that requires a different kind of deallocation than what `Box` would be doing to release the memory.

Comment: _What your T is doesn't really matter_... this is not true. `T` does matter. If the heap-allocated memory is pointed by an internal member of `T`, I don't even know what `Box` is managing (unless it gives special treatment to `T`, which would solve the problem). What `Box<T>` does know is a pointer to `slice`. It doesn't know the memory pointed by `slice`, which is the actual heap-allocated memory. Unless it gives special treatment to `slice`, which I cannot find on the reference documenation.

Comment: _You may be confusing this with a borrowed slice `&[i32]`_. This actually can be an answer to my question. Thanks for the patience to discuss with me. Gonna read more about it.

Comment: @sellibitze: That's an excellent explanation. Would you mind to amend these comments to your answer?

Comment: I created a new question just for the boxed slice discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39331341/how-to-pass-a-boxed-slice-boxt-to-a-c-function