# How to pass a boxed slice (`Box<[T]>`) to a C function?

Tags: rust, heap-memory, ffi

I want to expose a "dynamic array" to a C function. The C function will own the data and later will call a function of mine to free the data. So it'll look something like the following:

```
fn get_something(len: *mut usize) -> *mut u8;
fn dealloc_something(data: *mut u8, len: usize);
```

Internally I have a `Box<[T]>` (`my_vec.to_boxed_slice()`). I can get the size/length pretty easily, but I don't know which pointer I should return. If I pass the pointer returned from `boxed_slice.as_mut_ptr()` to `Box::from_raw()`, the application crashes. However, if I pass the pointer returned from `Box::into_raw`, I can't find a guarantee of memory layout (the pointer points to the first element of the array and will continue to do so for all future Rust versions).

What's the solution here?

Answer (score 2):

`Box::into_raw` returns a pointer to the beginning of the allocated storage. A slice is a contiguous sequence of items in memory. Therefore, the pointer points to the first item in the slice. If `Box::into_raw` returned anything else, it wouldn't be really useful.

The main difference between `boxed_slice.as_mut_ptr()` and `Box::into_raw` is that `Box::into_raw` takes ownership of the box but does not deallocate it, while `boxed_slice.as_mut_ptr()` just returns a copy of the pointer and leaves ownership of the `Box` to your function, so the compiler implicitly drops it before returning. This means that when you use `boxed_slice.as_mut_ptr()`, you are essentially returning a pointer to freed memory!

Comment: _This means that when you use `boxed_slice.as_mut_ptr()`, you are essentially returning a pointer to freed memory_... actually I was using `mem::forget`, but this isn't important.

Comment: Can you link me to a reference of such memory layout? `Box::into_raw` will return a pointer to the first element? If this is true, my question is answered and I don't need to ask anything else.

Comment: "Slices are a view into a block of memory represented as a pointer and a length." [doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/). Memory layout of slice data is unspecified. You need to call `as_mut_ptr` on the slice to get valid pointer to data.

Comment: @vinipsmaker: You might want to [file an issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues) (if there isn't one already) to ask for the documentation to be clarified.