# How to create a subscription for events in Windows using Rust and the winapi crate?

Tags: winapi, rust

I'm trying to subscribe to Windows events using [`EvtSubscribe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winevt/nf-winevt-evtsubscribe) from [the winapi crate](https://docs.rs/winapi/0.3.7/winapi/um/winevt/fn.EvtSubscribe.html), but I'm getting `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`.

I can not find an example in Rust, but did find a [C++ example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/subscribing-to-events).

My code that produces `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`:

```
fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let mut callback: winapi::um::winevt::EVT_SUBSCRIBE_CALLBACK = None;
        let mut session = std::ptr::null_mut();
        let mut signal_event = std::ptr::null_mut();

        let mut bookmark = std::ptr::null_mut();
        let mut context = std::ptr::null_mut();
        let channel_path = "Security";
        let channel_path: winnt::LPWSTR = to_wchar(channel_path);
        let query = "Event/System[EventID=4624]";
        let query: winnt::LPWSTR = to_wchar(query);

        let event_handle = winevt::EvtSubscribe(
            session,
            signal_event,
            channel_path,
            query,
            bookmark,
            context,
            callback,
            winevt::EvtSubscribeStartAtOldestRecord,
        );

        //println!("{:?}", &event_handle);
        println!("{:?}", &winapi::um::errhandlingapi::GetLastError());
    } //unsafe end
}

fn to_vec(str: &str) -> Vec<u16> {
    return OsStr::new(str)
        .encode_wide()
        .chain(Some(0).into_iter())
        .collect();
}

fn to_wchar(str: &str) -> *mut u16 {
    return to_vec(str).as_mut_ptr();
}
```

Comment: Your `&` in `println!` are unneeded ([Does println! borrow or own the variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30450399/155423)) and the explicit `return`s in your helpers are non-idiomatic, and `.chain(Some(0))` is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [`EvtSubscribe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winevt/nf-winevt-evtsubscribe) states:

> `SignalEvent`
>
> [...] This parameter must be `NULL` if the `Callback` parameter is not
>   `NULL`.
>
> `Callback`
>
> [...] This parameter must be `NULL` if the `SignalEvent` parameter is
>   not `NULL`.

The unstated implication here is that **exactly one** of these parameters must be provided. Passing both is explicitly disallowed, but passing neither would not make sense, as otherwise there would be no way for your code to receive the event.

Passing one of these values should cause the code to start working.

Editorially, this is a good example of where a Rust enum would have been a better way to model the API. This would clearly show that the two options are mutually exclusive and one is required:

```
enum Subscriber {
    EventObject(HANDLE),
    Callback(EVT_SUBSCRIBE_CALLBACK),
}
```

---

Incidentally, your implementation of `to_wchar` is incorrect and likely leads to memory unsafety. `to_vec` allocates memory, you take a pointer to it, then that memory is deallocated, creating a dangling pointer. The bad pointer is read by the C code inside of the `unsafe` block — part of the reason `unsafe` is needed.

You either need to use `mem::forget`, as shown in [How to expose a Rust `Vec<T>` to FFI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39224904/155423) (and then you need to prevent leaking the memory somehow), or you need to take a reference to the data instead of taking the raw pointer.